# Subsetting Lists to extract more than one element

Tags: r

Trying to subset so the subset produces `"h" "i"`

I've tried `l1[[c(2,6)]]` which only gives me `"h"` and `l1[[c(2,6:7)]]` which gave me an error.

Answer (score 1):

You need to request `l1[[2]][c(2, 6)]`. `l1[[2]]` is the second element of `l1`, and consists of the vector `c("c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i")`. You want elements 6 and 7 of that vector, so `l1[[2]][c(2, 6)]`.

```
l1 <- list(c("a", "b", "c", "d", "e"), c("c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "i"), c("d", "e", "f", "g"))
l1
#[[1]]
#[1] "a" "b" "c" "d" "e"
#
#[[2]]
#[1] "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"
#
#[[3]]
#[1] "d" "e" "f" "g"
#
l1[[2]]
#[1] "c" "d" "e" "f" "g" "h" "i"
l1[[2]][c(6, 7)]
#[1] "h" "i"
```